# Submit without redirection

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-validate, form-submit

I want to submit a form without redirect/refresh a page but using `jquery.validate`.
I try to do something like

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "#errorContainer",
    wrapper: "div",
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit(function () {
            return false;
        });
        $('#form-container').fadeOut(function () {
            $('#afterSubmit').fadeIn()
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

I tryed changing `form.submit` to

```
form.ajaxSubmit(function () { return false; });
```

Or

```
form.submit(function () {
    var options = {};
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

And many other variations.

When I just do the following code the form isn't submited.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
        return false;
}
```

What should I do to submit my form after validating and not being redirect?

Comment: If there are any errors within the script the page will comply with the forms' action statement. Use the browsers debugger to single step through your code to find the possible cause of the error.

Comment: Actually the debugger isnt stoping in my breakpoints. I dont really know why.

Comment: Check the console log as there maybe other errors on your page which are preventing the script from running.

Comment: No errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it. Please find working example here http://jsfiddle.net/rQu9W/
and make sure to add [jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js), [jquery.validate.js](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js), [jquery.form.js](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js) as in my jsFiddle example

```
$(function(){
  $("#myForm").validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        clearForm: true,//To clear form after ajax submitting
        success: function(){alert('done');}
      });
      return false;
    },

    invalidHandler: function(form) {
      alert('error');
    }

  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to make an ajax call:

```
var sendData = "action=do_action";
sendData += "&value=" + $("input.value").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "post.php",//Page to send our data to
    global: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: sendData,
    dataType: "html",
    async:false,
    success: function(data){
        //We could return JSON and then just parse that, but I usually just return values like this

        //create jquery object from the response html
        var $response=$(data);

        var results = $response.filter('div.results').text();//Or .html() if we want to return HTML to show                     

        if (results == "true") {
            alert("it works");
        }else{
            var reason= $response.filter('div.reason').text();
            alert(reason);
        }
    }
});
```

And the PHP would look like:

```
<?php
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if ($action == "do_action") {
        if (true) {
            echo "<div class='result'>true</div>";
        }else{
            echo "<div class='result'>false</div>";
            echo "<div class='reason'>Houston, we have a problem!</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why did someone down-vote this?  This works.  I've used variations of this on several sites as needed...

Comment: I'm sending files with this form and it dont use jquery.validate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to submit form without reloading page you have to use ajax submitting. Yes, for that you need to change form.submit to form.ajaxSubmit. But you need to include jQuery Form Plugin in addition to validation plugin. You can find more details about ajaxSubmit function of jQuery Form Plugin here. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api

Comment: Just add this plugin, no changes. Update the question.